# apply function on Maybe types?

Tags: function, haskell, option-type

New to Haskell and I can't figure out how apply a function (a -> b) into a list [Maybe a] and get [Maybe b]

```
maybeX:: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
```

The function is supposed to do the exact same thing as map, apply the function f on a list of Maybe statements and if it Just it returns me a f Just and if it's a Nothing just a Nothing.
Like the following example I want to add +5 on every Element of the following List :

```
[Just 1,Just 2,Nothing,Just 3]
```

and get

```
[Just 6,Just 7,Nothing,Just 8]
```

Really trying to figure this and I tried a lot but it always seems like it is something that I'm not aware of in the way of which this Maybe datatype works..
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15):

Let's start by defining how to act on a single `Maybe`, and then we'll scale it up to a whole list.

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
mapMaybe f Nothing = Nothing
mapMaybe f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

If the `Maybe` contains a value, `mapMaybe` applies `f` to it, and if it doesn't contain a value then we just return an empty `Maybe`.

But we have a *list* of `Maybe`s, so we need to apply `mapMaybe` to each of them.

```
mapMaybes :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
mapMaybes f ms = [mapMaybe f m | m <- ms]
```

Here I'm using a list comprehension to evaluate `mapMaybe f m` for each `m` in `ms`.

---

Now for a more advanced technique. The pattern of applying a function to every value in a container is captured by the `Functor` type class.

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

A type `f` is a `Functor` if you can write a function which takes a function from `a` to `b`, and applies that function to an `f` full of `a`s to get an `f` full of `b`s. For example, `[]` and `Maybe` are both `Functor`s:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap f Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)

instance Functor [] where
    fmap f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

`Maybe`'s version of `fmap` is the same as the `mapMaybe` I wrote above, and `[]`'s implementation uses a list comprehension to apply `f` to every element in the list.

Now, to write `mapMaybes :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]`, you need to operate on each item in the list using `[]`'s version of `fmap`, and then operate on the individual `Maybe`s using `Maybe`'s version of `fmap`.

```
mapMaybes :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
mapMaybes f ms = fmap (fmap f) ms
-- or:
mapMaybes = fmap . fmap
```

Note that we're actually calling two different `fmap` implementations here. The outer one is `fmap :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]`, which dispatches to `[]`'s `Functor` instance. The inner one is `(a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`.

---

One more addendum - though this is quite esoteric, so don't worry if you don't understand everything here. I just want to give you a taste of something I think is pretty cool.

This "chain of `fmap`s" style (`fmap . fmap . fmap ...`) is quite a common trick for drilling down through multiple layers of a structure. Each `fmap` has a type of `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`, so when you compose them with `(.)` you're building a higher-order function.

```
fmap        :: Functor g              =>             (f a -> f b) -> (g (f a) -> g (f b))
fmap        :: Functor f              => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
-- so...
fmap . fmap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b)          ->         g (f a) -> g (f b)
```

So if you have a functor of functors (of functors...), then *n* `fmap`s will let you map the elements at level *n* of the structure. Conal Elliot calls this style ["semantic editor combinators"](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).

The trick also works with `traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> (t a -> f (t b))`, which is a kind of "effectful `fmap`".

```
traverse            :: (...) =>               (t a -> f (t b)) -> (s (t a) -> f (s (t b)))
traverse            :: (...) => (a -> f b) -> (t a -> f (t b))
-- so...
traverse . traverse :: (...) => (a -> f b)            ->           s (t a) -> f (s (t b))
```

(I omitted the bits before the `=>` because I ran out of horizontal space.) So if you have a traversable of traversables (of traversables...), you can perform an effectful computation on the elements at level *n* just by writing `traverse` *n* times. Composing traversals like this is the basic idea behind the `lens` library.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that `mapMaybe` already exists and is called `fmap`, and `mapMaybes` can be obtained by composing list-targeted `fmap` with the maybe-targeted `fmap`, i.e. `mapMaybes = fmap . fmap`. Mind = blown. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're likely already aware of

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

...which is really just a special case of

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The latter works both on lists (where it behaves exactly like `map`) and on `Maybe`, because both are functors. I.e., both of the following signatures are valid specialisations:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

Now, your use case looks similar, but unfortunately `[Maybe a]` is not by itself a specialisation of `f a`, rather it has the form `f (g a)`. But note that we can just substitute the variable `α` for `g a`, i.e. for `Maybe a`, then we can use

```
fmap :: (α -> β) -> [α] -> [β]
```

i.e.

```
fmap :: (Maybe a -> Maybe b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
```

That looks even more like the signature you want! However we still need a function with signature `Maybe a -> Maybe b`. Well, look above... I repeat:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

This can be *partially applied*, i.e. when you have a function `φ :: a -> b`, you can easily obtain the function `fmap φ :: Maybe a -> Maybe b`. And that solves your problem:

```
maybeX :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
maybeX φ = fmap (fmap φ)
```

...or, if you want to get extra fancy,

```
maybeX = fmap . fmap
```

Answer (score 4):

[Note: this assumes familiarity with functors.]

Another approach is to use type-level composition as defined in `Data.Functor.Compose`.

```
>>> getCompose (fmap (+5) (Compose [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]))
[Just 6,Just 7,Nothing,Just 8]
```

You can abstract this into a defintion for your `maybeX`:

```
-- Wrap, map, and unwrap
maybeX :: (a -> b) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b]
maybeX f = getCompose . fmap f . Compose
```

(In fact, nothing in the definition assumes `Maybe` or `[]`, just the restricted type annotation. If you enable the `FlexibleContexts` extension, you can infer the type `(Functor g, Functor f) => (a1 -> a) -> f (g a1) -> f (g a)` and use it on arbitrary nested functors.

```
 >>> maybeX (+1) (Just [1,2])
 Just [2,3]
 >>> maybeX (+1) [[1,2]]
 [[2,3]]
 >>> maybeX (+1) Nothing -- type (Num a, Functor g) => Maybe (g a), since `Nothing :: Maybe a`
```

)

---

The `Compose` constructor composes the `[]` and `Maybe` type constructors into a new type constructor:

```
>>> :k Compose
Compose :: (k1 -> *) -> (k -> k1) -> k -> *
```

Compare:

```
Compose :: (k1 -> *) -> (k -> k1) -> k -> *
  (.)   :: (b  -> c) -> (a -> b)  -> a -> c
```

(The main difference is that `(.)` can compose any two functions; it appears that `Compose` and its associated instances require the last higher-kinded value to be applied to a concrete type, one of kind `*`.)

Applying the data constructor `Compose` to a list-of-Maybes produces a wrapped value

```
>>> :t Compose [Nothing]
Compose [Nothing] :: Compose [] Maybe a
```

As long as the arguments to `Compose` are themselves instances of `Functor` (as `[]` and `Maybe` are), `Compose f g` is *also* a functor, so you can use `fmap`:

```
>>> fmap (+5) (Compose [Just 1,Nothing,Just 2,Just 3])
Compose [Just 6,Nothing,Just 7,Just 8]
```

The `Compose` value is just a wrapper around the original value:

```
>>> getCompose $ fmap (+5) (Compose [Just 1,Nothing,Just 2,Just 3])
[Just 6,Nothing,Just 7,Just 8]
```

---

In the end, this isn't much different than simply composing `fmap` directly:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

The difference is that you can define the *type* with a function and get its accompanying `Functor` instance for free, instead of having to hand-code both.