# Why do the types in `(fmap . fmap) sum Just [1, 2, 3]` work?

Tags: haskell

I'm having the time of my life reading the wonderful [Haskell Programming from first principles](http://haskellbook.com/) and I came by the following example that I'm just not able to take apart (Page 1286 e-reader):

```
Prelude> (fmap . fmap) sum Just [1, 2, 3]
Just 6
```

It is obvious to me how the following works:

```
Prelude> fmap sum $ Just [1,2,3]
Just 6
```

And I already manually deconstructed `(fmap . fmap)` to understand how the types work. But when thinking about this as "lifting twice" it doesn't make sense, since I'm lifting over both the Just and List data constructors.

I typed out the following in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap)
(fmap . fmap)
  :: (Functor f, Functor f1) => (a -> b) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b)

Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap) sum
(fmap . fmap) sum
  :: (Num b, Foldable t, Functor f, Functor f1) =>
     f1 (f (t b)) -> f1 (f b)

Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap) sum Just
(fmap . fmap) sum Just :: (Num b, Foldable t) => t b -> Maybe b
```

I don't understand how to derive the last output. When feeding `(fmap . fmap) sum` the `Just` data constructor, How does the compiler know to replace both `f1` and `f` for `Maybe`? After I'll get a good answer here, how could I have figured it out myself?

Comment: Expand the definition of `.` in `(fmap . fmap)`. Then simplify. Then notice that one of your uses of `fmap` is taking a function as its second argument...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apply function on Maybe types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498896/apply-function-on-maybe-types)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, that question looks almost completely unrelated.

Comment: The accepted answer explains why and how this works.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The question here looks almost like the exact opposite: we have a function that *does* have this behavior and the question is why does it work. In the linked question, they describe the behavior and they are looking for an implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't understand how a particular answer works, line up the argument you are supplying with the type from the previous step.

```
Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap) sum
(fmap . fmap) sum
  :: (Functor f, Functor f1, Num b) => f (f1 [b]) -> f (f1 b)
```

So in order for this work, `Just` has to have type `f (f1 [b])`, and then `(fmap . fmap) sum Just` has to have type `f (f1 b)`.

```
Just :: (Functor f, Functor f1, Num b) => f (f1 [b])
```

It's not obvious what `f` or `f1` should be here, so let's try the RHS instead. We can cheat and ask GHCi to check what the actual value of `(fmap . fmap) sum Just` should be:

```
Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap) sum Just
(fmap . fmap) sum Just :: Num b => [b] -> Maybe b
```

But this *should* match:

```
(Functor f, Functor f1, Num b) => f (f1 b)
```

We're trying to figure out what `f` and `f1` are here. So we have to rewrite it a little bit so it has the same structure (remember that `->` is syntactic sugar and gets in the way sometimes):

```
(fmap . fmap) sum Just :: Num b => [b] -> Maybe b
-- Same as...
(fmap . fmap) sum Just :: Num b => (->) [b] (Maybe b)
-- Or...
(fmap . fmap) sum Just :: Num b => ((->) [b]) (Maybe b)
--                     Functor f = ((->) [b])
--                                Functor f1 = Maybe
```

So we can figure out that in order for the types to match, the `Functor f`  has to be `(->) [b]`… remember that functions are functors too! And the `Functor f1` is `Maybe`, which is a bit more obvious.

We can test this out:

```
Prelude> :t (fmap . fmap) sum :: Num b => ([b] -> Maybe [b]) -> ([b] -> Maybe b)
(fmap . fmap) sum :: Num b => ([b] -> Maybe [b]) -> ([b] -> Maybe b)
  :: Num b => ([b] -> Maybe [b]) -> [b] -> Maybe b
```

And GHCi thinks it type checks just fine.

The only part here that's easy to forget is just that `(->) [b]` is a valid functor!

Comment: Since `sum` has a more general type these days, you might want to give it a type signature.

Comment: In this situation it is just `Num a => [a] -> a` and the more general type signature does not change things.

Answer (score 9):

That isn't lifting over both `Maybe` and `List` (that would be `(fmap . fmap) sum (Just [1,2,3])`, which has a type problem), but over the function type `(->)` and `Maybe`.

```
Just :: a -> Maybe a
     -- ((->) a) (Maybe a)
     -- f (g a)   for f ~ ((->) a)  and  g ~ Maybe

(fmap . fmap) :: (a   -> b) -> f (g a  ) -> f (g b)
     -- Num x => ([x] -> x) -> f (g [x]) -> f (g x)
     -- Num x => ([x] -> x) -> ([x] -> Maybe [x]) -> [x] -> Maybe x
     --          ^             ^                     ^
     --          sum           Just                  [1,2,3]
```