# How does (fmap.fmap) sum Just [1,2,3] type check in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I do not understand how does this simple expression type check in Haskell

```
(fmap.fmap) sum Just [1, 2, 3]
```

The type for composition of fmaps is:

```
fmap.fmap
  :: (Functor f1, Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)
```

so I expected f1 ~ List and f ~ Maybe, which implies that type of the function should be Integer -> b. But if type-check it in ghci, I get:

```
t (fmap.fmap) _ Just [1, 2, 3]

<interactive>:1:13: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: [Integer] -> b
      Where: ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the inferred type of it :: Maybe b at <interactive>:1:1
    • In the first argument of ‘fmap . fmap’, namely ‘_’
      In the expression: (fmap . fmap) _ Just [1, 2, 3]
```

I see ghci deducing the type of the function to be [Integer] -> b. How is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717654/why-do-the-types-in-fmap-fmap-sum-just-1-2-3-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason to expect `f1 ~ []` and `f ~ Maybe`. Notice that you need `Just :: f (f1 a)`. We know `Just :: a -> Maybe a`. Therefore, in reality, `f ~ (->) a` and `f1 ~ Maybe`. Then you have

```
fmap . fmap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> Maybe b
--             ^^sum^^^    ^^^^^Just^^^^^    ^ [1, 2, 3]
```

Since we know that `[1, 2, 3] :: a`, we can deduce `a ~ [Integer]` now (defaulting the `Num`eric type to `Integer`).

```
fmap . fmap :: ([Integer] -> b) -> ([Integer] -> Maybe [Integer]) -> [Integer] -> Maybe b
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here’s a tip for how you can figure this kind of thing out in the future. You can ask the type of a subexpression in ghci using a wildcard (as long as you don’t have `PartialTypeSignatures` enabled).

```
:t ((fmap :: _) . (fmap :: _)) sum Just [1, 2, 3]
```

This tells you that the outer `fmap` is used at type `(a1 -> b) -> ([a] -> a1) -> [a] -> b` while the inner one is used at type `(a1 -> b) -> Maybe a1 -> Maybe b`. It should be clear that the inner `fmap` is simply acting on `Maybe`. The outer `fmap` looks more complicated at first glance, but it’s an instantiation of the type of `(.)`, which is `fmap` in the function reader functor.

```
(.)  :: ( y -> z) -> (  x ->  y) ->   x -> z
fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> ([a] -> a1) -> [a] -> b

x ~ [a]
y ~ a1
z ~ b
```

The functor here is `([a] ->)`, spelled `(->) [a]` in real code because Haskell doesn’t allow operator sections at the type level.

That tells you that the outer one is `(.)`, and from there you can inline the definitions step by step to see how this is evaluated.

```
(fmap . fmap) sum Just [1, 2, 3]
fmap (fmap sum) Just [1, 2, 3]
(.) (fmap sum) Just [1, 2, 3]
(fmap sum . Just) [1, 2, 3]
fmap sum (Just [1, 2, 3])
```

To reduce noise and avoid having to juggle so many type variables to determine which are relevant, you can fix some of the types with type signatures, here `Int` instead of `Num a => a`.

```
:t ((fmap :: _) . (fmap :: _)) sum Just [1 :: Int, 2, 3]
```

This gives `(a -> b) -> ([Int] -> a) -> [Int] -> b` for the outer `fmap` in the `(->) [Int]` functor, and `(a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b` for the inner `fmap` in `Maybe`.

And just for fun, going the other way, you can also replace the `(.)` with an `fmap`!

```
fmap fmap fmap sum Just [1, 2, 3]
```